# PHP Include Misplaced on Web Page / Processed late?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a really strange issue where, out of the three PHP Includes I'm using on a page, the FIRST one is getting processed LAST, and there's something throwing a wrench into the layout. Chrome completely ignores the `</div><!--col-md-4-->` on line 21.

Here's main.php (apologies for the mangled indentation):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Pathfinder Character Generator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="text-center">Pathfinder Character Generator</h1>
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid green">
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid yellow">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid black;">

    <!--Character Name-->
    <label for="cg_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text">

    <!--Ability Scores-->
    <?PHP include 'ability_scores.php';?>


  </div><!--col-md-4-->

  <div class="col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid red">

    <?PHP include 'core_races.php';?>
    <?PHP include 'core_classes.php';?>


     <!--Level-->
      <label for="cg_level">Level</label>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="20">

      <!--Feats & Spec. Abilities-->
      <br>
      <label for="FaSA">Feats &#38; Special Abilities</label>
      <textarea id="FaSA" name="FaSA" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder=""></textarea>

      <!--Submit -->
      <button type="submit">Build</button>

    </div><!--col-md-8-->
    </div><!--row-->
   </div><!--Container-->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is an image of Chrome's Dev Console when I load the page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzEC3.png

The `</div><!--col-md-4-->` on line 21 is simply gone. No clue what happened to it. I have a hunch that's my main issue, but heck at this point I'm at a loss. The page loads up and, as the Chrome Dev Console shows, "ability_scores.php" does indeed show up AFTER the other two php includes. Maybe I've been staring at this for too long...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: ability_scores.php

```
<?PHP
//--Ability Scores--
$core_abilities = array("STR","DEX","CON","INT","WIS","CHA");
echo "<table class='table-condensed'><tr><th>Skills</th><th></th></tr>";
foreach ($core_abilities as $abs){
  echo "<tr><td>$abs</td><td><input type='number' value='0' min='-99' max='99'></td></tr>";
};
echo "<br>";
?>
```

The other two .php files that I'm including are VERY similar:

core_classes.php

```
<?PHP
//--Classes--
$core_classes = array("","barbarian","bard","cleric","druid","fighter","monk","paladin","ranger","rogue","sorcerer","wizard");
echo "<select>";
foreach ($core_classes as $class){
  $class_name = ucfirst($class);
  echo $class;
  echo $class_name;
  echo "<option value='$class'>$class_name</option>";
};
echo "</select><br>";
?>
```

core_races.php

```
<?PHP
//--Races--
$core_races = array("","dwarf","elf","gnome","half elf","half orc", "halfling","human");
echo "<select>";
foreach ($core_races as $races){
  $race_name = ucfirst($races);
  echo "<option value='$races'>$race_name</option>";
};
echo "</select><br>";
```

Comment: What is the generated source? Could be the browser guess-closing unclosed elements.

Comment: May be the problem is in your ability_scores.php page can you post that...

Comment: Apologies, not sure what you mean by "generated source". The Chrome Dev Console output that I've linked to is what's being generated by Chrome when I try to open the site.

Comment: Oh hey yeah good call, give me a tick and I'll post the ability_scores.php page.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I didn't terminate the `<table>` in ability_scores.php.